# Angularjs Error: [$injector:modulerr] 'ngRoute'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Got an error trying to reproduce angularjs example

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html ng-app="lk">
        <head> 
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="lk.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="apiCtrl"> 
            <div> 
                {{ data }}
                {{ status }}
                <br>
                <button ng-click="fetch()">fetch</button>
                <br>    
                <input type="text" ng-model="text"></input>
                {{ text }}
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

# lk.js
    (function(){
        var app = angular.module("lk", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.controller("apiCtrl", ["$http", "$scope", function($scope, $http){ 
            $scope.method = "POST";
            $scope.url = "https://example.com/api";

            $scope.fetch = function() {
                $scope.response = null;

                $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url}).
                    then(function(response){
                        $scope.status = response.status;
                        $scope.data = response.data;
                    }, function(response){
                        $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
                        $scope.status = response.status;
                });
            };
        }]);
    });
```

Error: `Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Tried to move `ng-app` and `ng-controller` derectives between tags.

Tried to change `min.js` to full angular.

Following [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr), I added dependency according [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) manual.

Still no solution.

Comment: You aren't invoking the self-invoking function at the end. Maybe try that? Replace last line `});` with `})();`

Comment: thanks!, I'm so dumb )

Answer (score 1):

Change this one.

```
app.controller("apiCtrl", ["$http", "$scope", function($http, $scope){
```

Order is important when you injecting the service